# Clearing Cookies In Xamarin iOS Build NHttpCookieStorage Not Clearing Cookies For WebView

Tags: ios, xamarin, cookies, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Working on an app that uses Xamarin WebView, to run authentication.  Trying to delete login info on user log out or cancel. Here is my code, mind the debugging that's going on.  I already checked that the shared storage is empty, but something is going on because user login is still cached.  After logging out, if the webpage is brought up again, the user is automatically signed in again.  The code is running, as I am getting debugger output.

Code Snippet:
'

```
public void Clear()
       {
        NSHttpCookieStorage CookieStorage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
        foreach (var cookie in CookieStorage.Cookies)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(cookie);
            CookieStorage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
            
        }
    }
```

`

How I am Calling the Dependency Service
`DependencyService.Get<IClearCookies>().Clear();`

Answer (score 1):

Modified a swift example to C# for a sort of "hacky" solution:

```
public void Clear()
    {
        NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.RemoveCookiesSinceDate(NSDate.DistantPast);

        WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.FetchDataRecordsOfTypes(WKWebsiteDataStore.AllWebsiteDataTypes, (NSArray records) => {

        for (nuint i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
        {
                var record = records.GetItem<WKWebsiteDataRecord>(i);
                WKWebsiteDataRecord[] recordArray = new WKWebsiteDataRecord[record.DataTypes.Count];
                WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.RemoveDataOfTypes(record.DataTypes, NSDate.DistantPast, ()=> { });
            }

        });

    }
```